jq: error: tostring/1 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
I have a json array of objects in which I would like to create some string using some values. What I tried was:
cat a.json | jq 'map(.id+" "+tostring(.time))'

It gives the error:
jq: error: tostring/1 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:

If I omit the tostring, then the problem is of course that time is not a string but a number.
Is there a way to do this? I could do a workaround using sed+tr, but it is inelegant.

EDIT: It was suggested to include some sample input. Behold!
[{
    "id": "399",
    "time": 1705655705
},
{
    "id": "409",
    "time": 1723587399
}]


Does jq '.id + " " + (.time|tostring)' do what you want? If not, please show some example input and the expected output

There's only a tostring/0 function. Try (.time | tostring) instead.
jq 'map(.id + " " + (.time | tostring))' a.json

Alternatively, use string interpolation, which automatically converts to string:
jq 'map("\(.id) \(.time)")' a.json


Perfect, thank you!

I'm using the latest jq (1.7.1) and neither of the two suggestions work. I get error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ';' or ')'  and error (at a.json:1): Cannot index string with string "time"

@Ted It depends on your input data. OP used map and some field names, so the input is presumably some iterable (array or object) containing objects with those keys, one carrying a string, the other one a number. For example: [{"id":"a","time":1}, {"id":"b","time":2}]. (Also, the first approach missed a closing paren.)

@pmf Ah... yes, that makes sense. That's why questions like this should always contain some example of the input data. :-) jq '.[] | .id + " " + (.time|tostring)' would work as well then.
